# Where to start to understand nutrition

Tags: weight-loss, diet, nutrition

I want to lose weight and get to a health / stable position where regular exercise and a normal diet can maintain my weight loss. I'm wanting to lose between 20 - 40 lbs.

I have a good grasp on setting up an exercise routine, and have something in place now. I used to work with a trainer, and they explained everything in a way that made sense. Now I'm just making adjustments as I need.

The one thing that I didn't learn about was nutrition. My trainer gave me a scheduled diet, and I only ate exactly what they put on the schedule. This didn't give me an opportunity to learn, and this is the one area that I feel underinformed about.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a place to start to gain this knowledge?

Comment: This is likely to be closed as it's not a good fit for this site, but depending on how deep you want to go, I'd recommend either the Precision Nutrition or BTN Academy courses. Most books are opinionated based on the author's preferences (vegan, carnivore, keto, paleo, etc), so you either have to read everything and pick out the commonalities, or adhere to basic nutrition guidelines (like avoid processed food eating only meat, fish, veg and fruit) and experiment to see what you respond best to (some do better on high carb low fat, others high fat low carb, others somewhere in the middle).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this question is off-topic here. But I do invite you to join our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/324/the-locker-room) where it's less strict, but still full of competent people. It's a nice place for soft questions like this.

Comment: @Alec - You need at least 20 rep to participate in chat. I agree, this is a great chat question. And I have had nutrition courses as part of a kines degree, I really do recommend basic nutrition at a community college should be a part of learning to plan your own diet. It's diet neutral. :D :D

Comment: I forgot there was a rep requirement for chatting. Oh well, here's 10.